# Pc screen shows black and white lines then crashs

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, crash

this issue hapened just a few days ago while i was playing a game, the screen showed a few distorted and broken images of what was meant to be on screen. This showed up for about 5 sec before the pc crashed , i could not turn it on again without going into safe mode. I have now removed the graphics card (a gtx750ti) and my pc starts up fine . Does anyone think that they may know what might be wrong with the card or drivers. Cheers
[image: this is a photo i took of my pc trying to start up with graphics card in]

Comment: Looks like a dying card ...

Comment: Try a different video card to confirm the problem. Check if your motherboard comes with onboard video from your processor.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could repair your Windows 10 installation after removing all your video drivers by using In-place Upgrade. If the issue still insists, the issue could not relate to the software.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old but decided to answer as it may help persons who have this problem currently with HP Laptops. I get this instead of the spinning dots on startup.

I solved the problem by updating the firmware. Get your HP serial or product number, go to HP Drivers & Downloads, download the firmware, unzip, run the HP Bios Setup utility setup file (usually an insydeflash exe file), choose your empty USB drive as your recovery flash and save.

Take flash, insert into laptop, press start, press escape, press HP Diagnostics, Firmware Management, choose your flash, then file, confirm, update.

Hope this helps!